# jquery not working correctly in form with divs

Tags: jquery

I have a form which is formatted using divs to place the various inputs. I want to hide the submit button until all the inputs are filled in by the user. I am using jquery to achieve this and it works fine in an unformatted form. When I place the input boxes inside a div, the jquery no longer works. Can anyone suggest why this should be happening please?

Here is my code:

```
<script src="includes/jquery-2.0.3.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submit_button").hide();

    $('form > input').keyup(function(){
        var empty = false;
        $('form > input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });
        if (empty) {
                $("#submit_button").hide();
            } else {
                $("#submit_button").show();
            }
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="form">
<!-- The Results Entry Form - redirects to update page-->
<form action="ryder_front_update.php" method="post">
    <div id="title">
    <!-- Enter the name of the course for the form     -->
    EMG Ryder Cup - *FRONT* - Better-Ball RESULT
    </div>
<!-- Enter the name of file of players if necessary    -->  
    <div id="player">Select Player:&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span><select id="player_name" name="player" class="input" size="1" /></span>
                    <option value="null">Select player username</option>
                    <option value="247thDustoff">247thDustoff</option>
                    <option value="54david">54david</option>
                    <option value="alantudor7554">alantudor7554</option>
                    <option value="caucus">caucus</option>
                    <option value="crosshatch">crosshatch</option>
                    <option value="dollertree">dollertree</option>
                    <option value="Eviscera">Eviscera</option>
                    <option value="flubdubber">flubdubber</option>
                    <option value="FuzzyJones">FuzzyJones</option>
                    <option value="jchong">jchong</option>
                    <option value="jrinkc">jrinkc</option>
                    <option value="kerison">kerison</option>
                    <option value="Racenut14">Racenut14</option>
                    <option value="rikbeekman">rikbeekman</option>
                    <option value="robin1962">robin1962</option>                  
                    <option value="stevegeorge57">stevegeorge57</option>
                    </select>
    </div>
    <div id="holes">Hole scores: <!-- If I remove the "holes" div tags the jquery works perfectly -->
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1<input id="hole01" type="text" name="h1" class="input1"/>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;2<input id="hole02"  type="text" name="h2" class="input1"/>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;3<input id="hole03"  type="text" name="h3" class="input1"/>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;4<input id="hole04"  type="text" name="h4" class="input1"/>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;5<input id="hole05"  type="text" name="h5" class="input1"/>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;6<input id="hole06"  type="text" name="h6" class="input1"/>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;7<input id="hole07"  type="text" name="h7" class="input1"/>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;8<input id="hole08"  type="text" name="h8" class="input1"/>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;9<input id="hole09"  type="text" name="h9" class="input1"/>
    </div> <!-- If the above inputs are in the div the jquery code does not work-->
    <div id="submit">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit_button" width="52" value="Submit" height="19" border="0" />                  
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the `>` selector selects children. This obviously isn't what you want since your form's children are divs.

Answer (score 2):

The input elements are not children of the form they are descendants, so instead of [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) use [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submit_button").hide();

    $('form  input').keyup(function(){
        var empty = false;
        $('form  input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });
        if (empty) {
                $("#submit_button").hide();
            } else {
                $("#submit_button").show();
            }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2QMEG/)

Comment: Thank you - I have 7 children myself (more fool me!) and they are all descendants aren't they? If only I knew the difference! The thing is - what I don't understand is that the submit button is an "input".

Answer (score 0):

Since you have added the div into the form element, The `input` tags becomes `descendant` not the `children`

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#submit_button").hide();
    $('form input').keyup(function(){
        var empty = false;
        $('form input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });
        if (empty) {
                $("#submit_button").hide();
            } else {
                $("#submit_button").show();
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`parent > child` (Child Selector) get all the instant child while `parent child` (descendant selector) will search all element in hierarchy

Example:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2
    <ul>
      <li>Item 2.1</li>
      <li>Item 2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>

$("ul > li").addClass("newClass");
```

adds class "newClass" to 1 2 and 3 whereas:

```
$("ul li").addClass("newClass");
```

add class "newClass" to every list element(1, 2, 3, 2.1, 2.2).

so try:

```
$('form  input').keyup(function(){});
```